# Prevent using some APIs of a depending package

Tags: java, api, unit-testing

We have some code wrapping API of a third-party package, and now we don't want our team members to mistakenly use the third-party package directly, is there any way to prevent it? (Such as add some kind of checking in UT). Example:

Code in a third-party package (so we cannot change it):

```
class OrigProvider {  
    public static String getSomething() { return sth;}
}
```

Code in my package (we need to third-party package):

```
class MyProvider {  
    public static String getSomething() {  
        sth = OrigProvider.getSomething;   
        process(sth);   
        return sth;  
    }  
}
```

And in our code, if someone incorrectly use `OrigProvider.getSomething`, our program will be wrong silently, so how to guarantee no one use the `OrigProvider.getSomething`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of the ugly solutions would be to run static code analyzer and look for  `import` statements of that other library's packages in the code (except the code that wraps the library, of course). Make it a test, and it will fail every time someone uses the library directly

Comment: You can probably also encapsulate the code wrapping the API of a third-party library into a separate module and make you main codebase only dependent on this module, not on the third-party one

Comment: @Alexey Subach, static code analyzer is a little too tricky, although it should work.